# Sound not playing in project build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I have created some code that is linked to a canvas the code itself manages two buttons that switch between each other on click allowing the player to turn on and off the music. When I make a build the sound is always turned off and cant figure out why(Buttons function fine). Also to state that I use Playerprefs to save the setting, the same code is used in all my scenes. I only want to force start the audio and set my button to active for the first scene.(Start Scene)

```
  public AudioSource backgroundmusic;
public string sound;

public GameObject SoundOnButton, SoundOffButton;
public bool muted;



void Start ()
{

    backgroundmusic.Play();
    SoundCheck();

   if (sound == "enabled")
    {
        SoundOffButton.SetActive(false);
        SoundOnButton.SetActive(true);
    }

   if (sound == "muted")
    {

        SoundOffButton.SetActive(true);
        SoundOnButton.SetActive(false);
    }

}

private void Update()
{

}


public void SoundOFF()
{
    SoundOffButton.SetActive(false);
    SoundOnButton.SetActive(true);
    muted = false;

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Sound", "enabled");

    SoundCheck();

}

public void SoundON()
{

    SoundOffButton.SetActive(true);
    SoundOnButton.SetActive(false);
    muted = true;

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Button", "used");
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Sound", "muted");

    SoundCheck();


}

public void SoundCheck()
{
    sound = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Sound");

    if (sound == "enabled")
    {

        muted = false;
        backgroundmusic.Stop();
    }
    if (sound == "muted")
    {

        muted = true;
        backgroundmusic.Play();

    }

}
```

Comment: At a glance, I see a strange thing in your code: if (sound == "enabled"){ backgroundmusic.Stop(); } is it right?

Comment: I was testing various things to get the audio to work so at this point I am really not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for, I changed a few things here and there and now it works. Here is the code.

```
   public AudioSource backgroundmusic;
public string sound;

public GameObject SoundOnButton, SoundOffButton, Canvas;
public bool muted, notloaded = false;



void Start()
{


    SoundCheck();

    if (notloaded == false)
    {
        if (Canvas == true)
        {
            SoundON();
            notloaded = true;
        }
    }

}



public void SoundOFF()
{

    muted = false;

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Sound", "enabled");

    SoundCheck();

}

public void SoundON()
{


    muted = true;

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Sound", "muted");

    SoundCheck();


}

public void SoundCheck()
{
    sound = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Sound");

    if (sound == "enabled")
    {

        muted = false;
        SoundOffButton.SetActive(false);
        SoundOnButton.SetActive(true);
        backgroundmusic.Pause();
        Debug.Log("Enabled");
    }
    if (sound == "muted")
    {

        muted = true;
        SoundOffButton.SetActive(true);
        SoundOnButton.SetActive(false);
        backgroundmusic.Play();
        Debug.Log("Muted");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My first questions is: does it work on your editor? It was not clear to me.

Some things I'd like to point out about it:
Make sure you have a AudioClip attached to your audio source. Make sure that the volume is some value you can actually hear it. Make sure that the GameObject or the parents of the GameObject containing the AudioSource are not disabled at any time. Make sure your project is actually allowed to make sound (Windows or Mac audio mixer).

Not if none of that work. I'd start debugging.

At first disable the script you are using to start and pause your music and go to your AudioSource and select "Play on Awake", this should make your background music start with the game, if it's not, you'll now you have a different problem.

If it does play with the game, then make a simple script.

```
IEnumerator Start ()
{
    bool control;
    while (true)
    {
        control = !control;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
        if (control)
            backgroundmusic.Play ();
        else
            backgroundmusic.Stop ();
    }
}
```

Instead of Play () and Stop (), you can also use:

```
GetComponent <AudioSource> ().volume = 0; and GetComponent <AudioSource> ().volume = 1;
```

Try any of these solutions and let me know.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and did not work the way I needed it  to.